# How to make this scroll view scrollable?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to add a horizontal scroll view to my view controller, but when I run the app I can't scroll. Here's an image:

[image: https://ibb.co/12y6zmw]

How should I solve it?

Comment: You need to set the `contentSize` of the scroll view. Assuming you are using auto-layout, you need to add constraints between the subviews and the scroll view. When you do that, auto-layout engine will dynamically determine what the `contentSize` of the scroll view is, thereby permitting scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing here is how the constraints of the scroll view and its inner views are set.

You should first set constraint of the scroll view as you would do with another view, once this is done correctly it should have an x and y positions and also would be capable of know width and height.

After that you should set the constraints for inner views, making them push the boundaries of the container (the scroll view). So imagine you have 3 inner views you want to be set vertically:

The first one should have a top constraint to its container (scroll view), and a bottom to the second inner view.

The second one should have a bottom constraint to the third one.

The third one should have a bottom constraint to its container (scroll view).

This should satisfy all the calculation needs by AutoLayout.